# Link button to heading in same page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, react-router

I'm trying to link the button to the heading of the different sections on the same page but I couldn't figure out how to use.i can use a link from one class to another but how to link on the same class with a specific word. what I have done is

```
<Button className="sec-btn"> <a href="/ Antsy services"> Get Started</a> </Button>
```

I want when users click Get started button then link that to the "Antsy service" title on the same page.

```
<h1 className="heading-1">Antsy services</h1>
```

Comment: Is it for designing page like a Single page site ?

Comment: The question is a little vague to me, what do you mean by `link that to Antsy service`? . Do you want the page to just scroll to the heading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I understand from this question is you have a href anchor tag element that when clicked, you want to scroll down the page to a different element.

You can use IDs as a form of linking between elements on the same page.

#### Solution

Simply give the element you want to scroll to an ID and then in the anchor tag you can provide a link to it via href.

```js
<a href="#test">
  <button> click me </button>
</a>

<div class="space"></div>

<div id="test">
  <p> hello </p>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen for it so it's easier to see the effect visibly.

https://codepen.io/shanecreedon/pen/poJGovK

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is anchor links.

How to create and use them:

1. add `id="example"` to some element on the page
2. add `<a href="#example">Scroll me to example element</a>` on top of your page
3. click and see what will happen

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the id selector syntax like this. Heading should have an id selector...

```
<h1 id="heading-1">Antsy services</h1>
```

Then you can link to the section of the page like this:

```
<a href="/Antsy services#heading-1"> Get Started</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you're trying to build a Single Page Site with sections. For this, you have to use ID to all the Headers that you are about to navigate to.

Try this,

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <style>
      h1{
         height : 100vh;
         background: skyblue;
      }
      h2{
         height: 100vh;
         background: #c0c0c0;
      }
      h3{
         height: 100vh;
         background: #a0faf9;
          
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
     <a href="#home">Home</a>
     <a href="#services">Services</a>
     <a href="#contact">Contact</a>

  
     <h1 id="home">Home Section</h1>
     <h2 id="services">Services Section</h1> 
     <h3 id="contact">Contact Section</h1> 
  </body>
</html>
```